ECSで秘密鍵はどう管理する？
環境は、ECS上で動いているlaravelでAws\CloudFront\CloudFrontClientのaws sdkを使用しています。
セキュリティ上の問題からpemファイルはgithub上で管理できないため、外部（secrets managerなど）から設定する必要があります。
sdkで使用されるprivate_keyはファイルパス指定のため、pemファイルの中身だけ外部から渡すのではなく、ファイルごと渡す、もしくはファイルを新たに作成するなどが必要になります。
外部からファイルを渡す方法、または中身だけ外部から渡しファイルのみ新たに作成するなど方法はありそうですが、適切な管理方法はあるでしょうか。

ECSであれば、機密情報はSecretsManager、またはパラメータストアのSecure Stringに保管しておいて環境変数で渡すのが一般的ではないでしょうか。
タスク定義のエントリーポイントやコマンドの部分でそれをどこかにファイルとして保存するように処理すればよさそうです。
他にはEFSに保管しておいて、ECSのタスク起動時にそれをマウントするとかでしょうかね。
